# What debian lenny repo i need to install rake?

Tags: repository, rake, debian

This is my sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian lenny main
deb http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian lenny contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main contrib
deb http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib
deb-src http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib
```

`apt-cache search rake` finds nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"rake" package is in section "main" of the Debian repositories.

```
http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=rake&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all
```

With your sources.list must be enough. Remember to do `svn update` first.

And maybe you can clean the sources.list a little:

```
deb http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian lenny main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main contrib
deb http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib
deb-src http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib
```

Comment: Thanks, cleaning the sources.list fixed problem :)